# Is there any name for this kind of graphic?

Tags: background

I'm talking about the background of this picture. For sure It's not a simple solid blue color. Is there any specific name for it?

[image]

Comment: Sure graph or inforgraphic

Comment: @joojaa I believe the OP is focused on the *background*; the texture-like aspect

Comment: @Arsam I think what you're referencing is a paper-like or grainy texture

Comment: Looks like an old (somewhat cliché) "blueprint" paper to me. My understanding is that architects don't actually use that type of blueprint.. haven't for decades (like since the 40s/50s).

Comment: @Scott it was never used as such. it was just the copying process that made them blue. the originals were still black and white. and as soon as the tech improved then the blue was out. and your timeframe is a bit off blueprints are 1840's technology

Comment: Yeah.. that's why I added "cliché" @joojaa -- lay-people *think* thats what architects/engineers use... but it really hasn't been for a very, very, very long time. Tell ya what.. wish I had that branding power.. the general population thinks long deprecated visuals are still valid `:)`

Comment: @Scott yeah or a hundred years in fact. A thing a monk once said comes to mind: "be careful what you put in peoples heads, its really hard to get it out"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is difficult to see the details, the closest basic texture it looks is "Gritty", or in Illustrator or Photoshop it would be "Grain".

Take a look at an example like [this](https://elements.envato.com/gritty-concrete-textures-5Y9WV2). It is called Gritty Concrete Textures, and it displays how the details change as you look both horizontally and vertically. You would be able to change the size of textures without it affecting the texture because they are vectors.

Here is another example from [Freepik](https://freepik.com):
[image: Grain texture]